# How to set default settings for options in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I searched all over , couldnt get this question anywhere in the stackoverflow.
So here is my question:

In the menu creation / edit - we get a big list of options - Categories/Blog Layout , etc options.
There are options to select "Use global".

I am interested to know where to change this options. I am finding it hard to make my website look uniform because of this.

Please help.

Thanks,
Madhu

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

There are more things related to this.For global settings case in menu , article components are different options.

Such as for menu items use global option is set in menus->menu manager - >options(on the tool bar menu).

For articles use global section are you can find at contnet->article manager ->(options on the tool bar).

for other components layout like Virtuemart ,K2 etc they have their own option button in their layout.

Hope this may help you..